# Marklogic SVC-FILRD error even when file is present on the filesystem

Tags: marklogic

I have restored a forest from a forest backup. I am trying to open a binary file but I get an error -

```
1.0-ml] SVC-FILRD: xdmp:subbinary(fn:doc("mc-2022-vol57/mc-2022-vol57.ch06/graphic/mc-2022-vol57.ch06_g05.tif")/binary(), 1, 8) -- File read error: open '/var/opt/MarkLogic/Forests/content-lake-raw-1/Large/3fe/ffa6dd5438c09a48': No such file or directory
```

even though I can clearly see this location in the s3 bucket from where I am doing the restore. Why are some files not getting restored?

Answer (score 0):

If the file exists in the backup, but is not being created after the restore then something may have gone wrong with the restore. You didn't mention which version of MarkLogic you are using, but in recent versions the underlying mechanism for S3 communications has changed. There were a few bugs reported for S3 backup/restore since that change that have since been addressed, so it might be helpful to either test with the latest version of MarkLogic or as a test, enable the `Use Old S3 Impl` trace event and try restoring again.

Trace events need to be enabled and added by an administrator using the following steps:

1. Log into the Admin Interface.
2. Select Groups > group_name > Diagnostics
3. The Diagnostics Configuration page appears
4. Click the true button for trace events activated
5. Enter the trace event `Use Old S3 Impl` to enable the diagnostic event
6. Click the OK button to activate the event(s)

If this issue is repeatable, it might be worth [reporting it with a MarkLogic Support case](https://help.marklogic.com/Default/Base/Default).

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. I am sorry I got the question wrong. I have updated it now. The file is not present on the ec2, it is present on the s3 bucket from where I am restoring into marklogic.